# Android autotext and autosuggest ... how do these differ?

Tags: android, textview, spell-checking, android-edittext

An Android TextView can have its inputType parameter set to textNoSuggestions, which "indicates that the IME should not show any dictionary-based word suggestions". Presumably, if this is not specified, the default is for suggestions to be shown.

It can also have its AutoText parameter set to either true or false. "If set, this specifies that this TextView has a textual input method and automatically corrects some common spelling errors. The default is "false"."

Does anyone know how these two parameters interact? For example, what happens if suggestions are not shown but autotext corrections are made?